# AngularJS, Node.js, node module 'phantom'... Injection error, angularjs trying to load my directive + Suffix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, phantomjs

When I load an AngularJS page it loads fine. No console errors. Content shows as expected.

When I load the same page from another app, using Node module 'phantom' it fails with error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=WidgetsProvider%20%3C-%20Widgets%20%3C-%20dashboardWeightTableWidgetDirective

From the angular site this link equates to: `Unknown provider: WidgetsProvider <- Widgets <- dashboardWeightTableWidgetDirective`

Please notice the directive name. "`dashboardWeightTableWidgetDirective`". The directive is named, and referred to everywhere in my code as: "`dashboardWeightTableWidget`".

What is happening is that it is hitting this line in angular.js file:

```
$CompileProvider.$inject = ['$provide', '$$sanitizeUriProvider'];
function $CompileProvider($provide, $$sanitizeUriProvider) {
  var hasDirectives = {},
      Suffix = 'Directive',
      COMMENT_DIRECTIVE_REGEXP = /^\s*directive\:\s*([\w\-]+)\s+(.*)$/,
      CLASS_DIRECTIVE_REGEXP = /(([\w\-]+)(?:\:([^;]+))?;?)/,
      ALL_OR_NOTHING_ATTRS = makeMap('ngSrc,ngSrcset,src,srcset'),
      REQUIRE_PREFIX_REGEXP = /^(?:(\^\^?)?(\?)?(\^\^?)?)?/;
```

and then trying to use that altered name to do what looks like a dependency injection. But this is a directive. Definition showing below.

```
angular.module('directives')
    .directive('dashboardWeightTableWidget', function (Data, Widgets, $interval, $window, $q) {
```

Again, this only happens when I am trying to render the page through phantom, using the node module that comes with this command: `npm install phantom`

My relevant phantom code looks like this:

```
const phantom = require('phantom');
let _ph;

exports.initPhantom = function() {
    phantom.create().then(ph => {
        _ph = ph;
 })
}

exports.processPage = function(conf) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("creating phantom page ...");

    let _page, _interval, _pageReady;
    let _outObj = _ph.createOutObject();

    return _ph.createPage().then(function (page) { ....
        return _page.open(conf.options.viewerUrl);
    }).then (function(){
        setTimeout(() => {
              return _page.render(conf.options.filePath).then(function (status)                                                                       {
                   page.close();
              })

...
```

One additional comment: I can't figure out how to get into the loading page client-side code during the phantom render call. If I could do that, then I could step through the code and possibly see what is broken during the rendering. If anyone knows this, I would be grateful for that answer too. You know, "teach a man to fish".

```
let processPage = function(conf) {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    let instance = null;
    let phInstance = null;
    let reportPage = null;
    console.log("creating phantom page ...");

    let _outObj = _ph.createOutObject();

    return _ph.createPage()
      .then(function (page) {
        reportPage = page;
        _outObj.urls = [];
        _outObj.pageReady = false;

        page.property("customHeaders", {
          "Authorization": conf.options.authorization
        });
        page.property("paperSize", {
          //format: "Letter",
          format: "A4",
          margin: {
            top: '0.75in',
            left: '0.52in',
            bottom: '0.75in',
            right: '0.52in'
          }
        });
        page.property('setting', {
          resourceTimeout: 60000, // times out after 1 minute
          javascriptEnabled: true,
        });
        page.on('onConsoleMessage', function (msg, out) {
          console.log("on console msg ");
          console.log(msg);
          // should be 0 when page Widhgets are all loaded
          var loaded = msg.indexOf('getSeriesLoadingCount') > -1 ? true : false;
          if (loaded) {
            console.log('Message from console: ', msg, loaded);
            out.pageReady = true;
            _outObj = out;
          }
        }, _outObj);
        page.on('onResourceRequested', function (requestData, networkRequest, out) {
          // console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(requestData, undefined, 4));
          out.urls.push(requestData.url);
        }, _outObj);
        page.on("onError", function (msg, trace) {
          console.log("Error recorded: ", msg);
          trace.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
          });
        });
        page.on("onResourceError", function (resourceError) {
          page.reason = resourceError.errorString;
          page.reason_url = resourceError.url;
          console.log("Resource Error:", resourceError.errorString);
          console.log("Resource Url:", resourceError.url);
        });
        return page.open(conf.options.viewerUrl);

      })
      .then((status) => {
        let _pageReady = false;
        let _nbTrials = 0;
        // this setInterval loop is here to cycle through and check for the page being ready. It uses the PhantomJS event
        // property called 'onConsoleMessage'. This setting can be found above. It is a listener. In that listener we are
        // watching for a string that has a value of 'getSeriesLoadingCount' when the listener sees this text, it sets the
        // pageReady value to true. then this loop lets the code inside run. Primarily the rendering of the page to a file
        // in the temp directory of the server.
        _interval = setInterval(() => {
          _outObj.property('pageReady').then(function (ready) {
            if (ready === true) {
              clearInterval(_interval);
              return reportPage.render(conf.options.filePath).then(function (status) {
                reportPage.close();
                if (status) {
                  console.log('viewerUrl', conf.options.viewerUrl);
                  resolve(conf);
                } else {
                  console.log("cannot render page");
                  reject(conf);
                }
              });
            } else {
              ++_nbTrials;
              // 2 minutes
              if (_nbTrials >= 40) {
                return reject("too long generating the report");
              }
            }
          });
        }, 300);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("MAIN CATCH ERROR");
        console.log(error);
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: You probably have a timing issue. Look at your promise chain. You return from setTimeout, but that value is just discarded. You need to return a promise and resolve it in the callback

Comment: Aluan Haddad... Using the code that I added to my issue:      The strange directive error pops up immediately. Then, 20 seconds later, my console prints out and an empty_web_page.png arrives. This suggests the errors are happening at the page.open call. Do you still suspect a promise chain, timing issue?

Comment: It is a distinct possibility. Regardless the presence of the return statement indicates a bug, one way or another. It's not doing what it looks like it thinks it's doing.

Comment: `.then(() => new Promise(resolve => {setTimeout(resolve);})).then(()=> _page.render(conf.options.filePath).then(() => {page.close();})`

Comment: I also realized something else: Your outer promise constructor call is broken. You neither resolve nor reject it and again, the `return` is an error.

Comment: Is this one of those questions where the code wasn't working and you added more code which further breaks the code? It really looks that way. The `phantom.create()` promise isn't properly chained with the `_ph.createPage()` promise. And then the promise constructor isn't resolved. And then there is a `setTimeout` call. Was `setTimeout` added as an erroneous effort to get broken code working?

Comment: georgeawg... you almost have it right. This is inherited code that wasn't working. I was trying to step lightly at first because this is a large and complicated app. I only added the setTimeout trying to see if timing was the issue. From reading my feedback I have layed a heavier hand on this and straightened out my promise chain... I believe. With that in mind I am going to edit my original post to reflect my current code, as the problem still exists. And yes, it is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

Self Answer:

Ultimately I had a file inclusion issue. Which is really inconsequential at this point. I do think, however, there are 3 points worthy of taking away from my journey.

```
Unknown provider: WidgetsProvider <- Widgets <- dashboardWeightTableWidgetDirective
```

1. I thought this error was telling me I had a problem with dashboardWeightTableWidgetDirective. To angular that is where the error is occurring. But what this error is actually telling me is that I have an error in the dashboardWeightTableWidget directive, and the error is that it cannot find the provider "Widgets". Therefore, the actual problem was a bug in the file that was providing "Widgets".
2. As a part of the internal workings of angular, it adds the suffix "Directive" to every directive for internal tracking for it's directive factory. When my directive was failing, it did actually have the value "dashboardWeightTableWidgetDirective" due to this internal functionality. Thus the report. But what I had to fix was the "Widgets" part.
3. As an added piece of information; the file "widgets" load was failing on the variable declarations using "let". Something about the phantomjs headless browser could not deal with that instantiation. Thus my code working properly in the headed browser, but not when called by phantomjs. Ultimately the problem was solved by setting all my variable instantiations back to "var".

I hope this saves someone from the countless hours I gave away trying to find this error.